# CSS Background-position Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Ok so I have set a background-position property on an element through a class declaration. And for some reason chrome, and I'm assuming all webkit browsers, ignore the background-position property.

I have like so

```
.buttonholder {
background-position: -175px 0px;
}
```

and

```
<span class='buttonholder'>
<a href='index.php'>Home</a>
</span>
```

I took out the firebug type tool in chrome and for some reason the tag comes up like so:

```
<span class='buttonholder' style='background-position: 0% 0%; '>
```

Even though there is no specific style declaration inside the elements tag. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Edit: Apparently people think I am trying to use this as a way to position the element. Which is false. I'm trying to position a background image.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-webkit-background-position`?

Answer (score 3):

Add this:

```
background-position-x: -175px;
background-position-y: 0px;
```

Also see:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57963

Answer (score 2):

In chrome, to solve this bug, you need to use percent in background position.
When change position will works fine.

Hope its help

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, I had a similar issue to this, where I use JavaScript to dynamically reposition an element using the `jquery('[element]').css('background-position')` property and it wasn't showing up in Chrome.

I found that I had also had the element declared in the CSS in an external stylesheet:

```
[element] {
  background: #becfd3 url([background image]) no-repeat 140px 60px;
}
```

I ended up removing the `140px 60px` part of the element in the stylesheet and it worked for me. Maybe it'll work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna positionate something check for position: absolute | relative | fixed | static, and add top, and left according to w3c standard. I have no idea of background-position, but I'm pretty sure that what you do with this property can also be handle with my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with this and found chrome and other webkit browsers to render background positions without any issues. I used a single background declaration like this:

```
background: url(http://www.example.com/image.png) -175px 0;
```

Perhaps you could declare the style in the same way and see if that works.

Comment: It didn't make any difference. For whatever reason it continues to explicitly set a background position style property on the element even though there is no style attribute even added to said element

Comment: Have you tried adding !important to see if there is possibly a conflict? As in: background: url(http://www.domain.com/image.png) -175px 0 !important;

Comment: Ahh adding in important seemed to fix the problem and bring up others but the others should be more easily fixed

Answer (score 0):

The `background-position` property is used to position background images only, not the elements themselves. If you'd like to learn CSS positioning in ten steps, see http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Reference for `background-position`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position (info applies to Mozilla and Webkit)

Comment: I realize its supposed to do background images.... I'm not stupid I'm working with a background image

Comment: I didn't say you were stupid; I'm trying to help you. Setting the "background-property" won't do anything unless "background-image" is also set. Perhaps include a link to the page in question so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

This one almost works for me. It positions the element to the right side, but it doesn´t take the .3rem into consideration in Chrome browser.
The background-position-y works in Chrome as well.

```
#email.active {
    background-image: url(./images/icon-error.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: right, .3rem !important;
    background-position-y: center;
}
```

In Safari it has worked in the following way for me, I didn´t have any issues with the positioning in Safari.

```
#email.active {
    background-image: url(./images/icon-error.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: right .3rem !important;
    background-position-y: center;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33305386)